# Business logic and data mappers in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, data-modeling

I reluctantly adopted a data mapper approach for my current project but I've been left a little confused.

**Business Model**

A worker has a name, a set of working hours, and a cost.

**Data Model**

A worker is made up of a labour type and a working pattern (three different tables).  The cost of the worker is calculated based on a combination of the labour type and the working pattern.

**My problem...**

I seem to have two different models, one that represents business logic and one that represents data structure.  I was of the understanding that my model should represent the business logic, but what happens when I want to insert a new worker?  This is done using a form with two drop downs, the working pattern & the cost, the id's of which are not needed by the business model.

Confused?  I am.

Comment: If you create your object model, populate it with the data, and then pass to the data mapper so that it choose where to insert using your data model do not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no real support for data models with the zend framework. But [weierophinney](http://weierophinney.net/matthew/archives/202-Model-Infrastructure.html) does a realy good job to show how they could be implemented. Another very good description is [this one](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/the.model).
Usually a model represents the data and includes the logic. The data model is a backend independed way to write/get data. For the model and the application it doesn't matter from where the data comes. Thus the datastorage can be exchanged without having to touch anything else.

Comment: What do you mean with "No real support"? Can you clarify?

Comment: @kayne : It currently sees datasets from a database as model. Thus the model is tied to a specific storage and this is completly against the idea of models. Generally a model is only an object that represents data and buisness logic - totally independend of the storage engine. Why is this a bad idea? Weir O'Phinney does a great job in explaining this (Link 1).

Comment: But there's a real implementation: You can have an `Model_Worker`, an `Model_WorkerDataMapper` and finally an `Model_DbTable_Worker`

Comment: @kayne: That's how you/I would implement it. But there are no abstracts/interfaces for a model or mapper in the zend framework. Only for the Model_DbTable_Worker.

Comment: It's Keyne not Kayne =P. I can't see comments notifications if you type the wrong username... Back in the subject, I agree with you. But, what's the name of the pattern that define a separeted model class and its common methods? Is there one?

Comment: @keyne (!): It's actually not a single design pattern but a (large) group of design patterns that all desribe that idea. For the model it's common name is "Domain Object Model" while the mappers (to what backend ever) are simply called "Data Mapper" ;). To get the basic idea: http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors#zfbook.implementing.the.domain.model.entries.and.authors.the.domain.model.and.database.access.patterns . Or in great detail: Martin Fowler's "Patterns Of Enterprise Application Architecture" (POEAA).

Comment: Thanks! Domain Model is the name. http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/ In this case Domain Logic with Data sources.

Comment: Thank you both for the comprehensive answer and discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Default data modelling in Zend Framework (Zend_Db_Table) isn't probably the best choice for object oriented data modelling.

Try using ORM like Doctrine (http://www.doctrine-project.org/) it allows you to create domain object model and almost transparently store it in database. This way you can have business model and data model combined in single classes.

Comment: Can you enumerate the reasons that make zend-db-table a bad choice?

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing. Seems like many people follow this marketing drumbeat originated by GOF, Martin Fowler, Eric Evans books but almost no one seem to be able to actually explain why my projects would benefit from their ideas. in contrast -  Wordpress doesn't have a single abstract or interface class - and that's a very successful product. I decided that it probably better to be result oriented than spend ages in analisys-paralisys with nowhere-to-be-found benefits.

Comment: @Andre - Wordpress being quite popular doesn't mean it's written well. I didn't really like working with it's codebase and found it hard to adapt to my needs. Probably because the authors were more focused on the results than making something that was easily extendable/scalable/adaptable. Depending on your project it may be overkill going for full-on data modelling or using ORMs but If you're thinking about the subject then it's worth investigating the alternatives.